# Error while building rust with libp2p-0.53.1

Tags: rust, build, rust-cargo, libp2p

I am trying to upgrade a project, that has vendored crates, from using libp2p 0.46 to 0.53.1 but I am getting an error when I try to build it.

```bash
error[E0599]: no method named `as_pin_mut` found for struct `Pin<&mut either::Either<A, B>>` in the current scope
   --> <project>/vendor/crates/libp2p-core-0.39.2/src/either.rs:147:20
    |
147 |         match self.as_pin_mut() {
    |                    ^^^^^^^^^^ help: there is a method with a similar name: `as_mut`

For more information about this error, try `rustc --explain E0599`
```

Any ideas why this might happen?

Comment: What version of `either` does `libp2p-core` use in your dependency graph? You can see by running `cargo tree -p libp2p-core --depth=1`. I ask because their [dependencies](https://crates.io/crates/libp2p-core/0.39.2/dependencies) say it relies on `either` v1.5+ but [`.as_pin_mut()`](https://docs.rs/either/1.8.0/either/enum.Either.html#method.as_pin_mut) was only added in v1.8.

Comment: I have `either-1.6.1` maybe that's why. I'll try to upgrade `either`

Comment: @kmdreko updated either to `1.8.1` what did this. I can build the project now. Thank you for this :D

Answer (score 2):

It seems `libp2p-core` uses `either` v1.5 as a dependency but the latest version is using a method only available in `either` as of v1.8. So when you updated to the latest version of `libp2p`, your existing version of `either` (v1.6.1 apparently) was "still good" so it wasn't updated along in tandem.

The quick fix would just be to update the version of `either` using `cargo update`:

```
cargo update -p either
```

I have [filed an issue](https://github.com/libp2p/rust-libp2p/issues/3909) so hopefully this gets addressed.